# Is using a pattern on a completely wrong way a terrible mistake

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, dto

This is maybe a strange question, but I just trying to understand my colleague.
I know what is DTO, and what should be on it, but not that long time ago I found the whole micro-service written on the way where all DTO classes had just protected properties with public methods that throw *DTOException (there are multiple types of DTOExceptions), also I didn't find that DTO class is ever serialized. Also, one interesting thing is that every single DTO class has test coverage... I think that colleague completely miss-understand what DTO is.

I found that as a really bad example, and I talked to my colleague who wrote that microservice from scratch, trying to understand why is done like that.
His argument is that it's like that because he didn't have time to do it better; He told me that

> he had an issue to validate some state on DTO objects

where I suggested to him that he could do that by providing the static class with static functions as a helper until he thinks about something better, and keep DTO clean, on that I got the answer

> that we all solve the problems in a different way, and at the end, it's
>   important that software work.

I found that argument as not valid since somehow I'm not able to accept that senior developer is able to provide something like that, with that arguments. Having a DTO with protected properties, holding business logic, throwing errors, never serialized, having test coverage is just not a way to go, and if you ask me, should be an example of how things should not be done. Using something on a completely wrong way, for me, it's not a small thing, especially in this case where **simple** DTO is used on the wrong way

I already know that the code I saw is terrible, but somehow I'm not used to seeing such things, and just try to understand and get feedback from other ppl, is such things normal, and how they look at it. Maybe I should not change my job, in the first place...

==================
**So I need to ask you:** ==================

- Is using a pattern on a completely wrong way a terrible mistake?

  - are mistakes like that normal in software development, should be tolerated?
  - Is it fine that someone who is a senior dev to provide such a code?
  - Do you find his excuse as valid?
  - Could you call him `Experienced Developer`

EDIT:
As @telastyn mention, it's not clear from my question how the code looks like, it's something like this, but with a lot of more public methods and logic (original code was done in PHP, here as an example I'm using C# because of readability :) and also because I'm not able to share the original code because of NDA ):

```
public class SomeDTO
{
    protected string prop1 {get;set;}

    protected string prop2 {get;set;}

    public void BuildFromSomeOtherDTO(string something)
    {
        if (something === "invlid")
        {
            throw DTOException();
        }

        this.prop1 = "something";
        this.prop2 = "something else";
    }

    public void SetProp1(string val) 
    {
        this.prop1 = val;
    }

    public void SetProp2(string val) 
    {
        this.prop2 = val;
    }

    public void GetProp1() 
    {
        return this.prop1;
    }

    public void GetProp2() 
    {
        return this.prop2;
    }

    //public string ToJson()
    //{
    //    THERE IS NOTHING LIKE THIS, LOOKS LIKE THAT DTO IS NEVER 
    // SERIALIZED! Sorry for comments where I wrote that there is, I was 
    // already shocked with the things I saw and originally share here with 
    // all. And also, looked like that public getters are there just because 
    // of DTO Tests
    //}
}


class SomeDTOTest : BaseTest
{
    public BaseDTO TestCanCreateInstance
    {
        var instsance = this.GetClassForTest();
    }

    public TestCanBuildInstanceFromSomeOtherDTO
    {
        var someOtherDTO = new SomeOtherDTO();

        var instance = SomeDTO();

        instance.BuildFromSomeOtherDTO(someOtherDTO);

        // here some checks if build was done correct
    }

    protected GetClassForTest
    {
        return new SomeDTO();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is unclear what the code actually looked like. Public properties that _just_ throw are nonsensical. Though your colleague is correct that functioning is the most important software trait.

Comment: Recommended: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2009/09/23/the-duct-tape-programmer/

Comment: DTO classes should be only DTO, nothing more! No business logic, it should be only a layer to transfer data from lower layer to higher and vice versa, logic should be inside service.
I'm not tolerate for such developers and don't think, that we should close eyes on it :)

Comment: I still don't think your code example captures what you are asking about. I just see a class with no public properties, and a few public setters with no way of getting data back out of this object.

Comment: @user285336 You get zero points for having an opinion, IMO. [Explain *why*](https://fragiledeveloper.com/2019/06/09/the-principle-of-applying-principles-(POAP).html) a DTO should have no behavior. (In a compelling answer, preferably.)

Comment: @greg-burghardt (Greg Burghardt)
That is actually one of the issues, serialization is done by calling public methods on the class (somehow he explained me that is normal to have something like that in PHP :) )... The whole code is full of bad examples, I just took one.... And there are a lot of stuff that are done wrong, you can imagine if simple DTO is done like that, how is everything else....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are **terrible** mistakes like that normal?

Yes. Even far more terrible examples, this is on the "ugh.." level and not the "wtf" level (although it depends on your experience with/tolerance to bad code). Maybe it was his first microservice, maybe he just "had a fib" and his architecture went in the wrong direction and he didn't have the time/energy/skill to fix it (after all, it worked). If you're lucky, you work in a place where they are **not** normal, but that usually means that you're an experienced developer, working with other experienced developers. In many cases "junior and senior" dev actually means "junior and less junior" (not that there's any way to accurately measure developer skill).

> Should they be tolerated?

That's a very broad question. I think it's common for junior developers to imagine some kind of godlike programmer that doesn't make mistakes, and they hope that they can one day be like that. Everyone makes mistakes and some mistakes are more serious than others. You could keep rewriting your code all day if you were to strive for perfection, but programming is not a beauty contest.

In this case if the "damage" is limited to DTO classes in a single microservice, that's probably not a big deal. It will cause confusion among new developers, but in the grand scheme of things it's probably insignificant. Of course it can be harmful if younger devs understand it as a valid programming pattern, in which case it can result in [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), which in the worst case spreads with the dev like a virus into other places (until someone says "why on earth did you do it like this"). I prefer to defensively comment my bad code so people don't assume I'm writing code like that just because I'm stupid.

> Is it fine for a senior dev to produce such code?

It's not a choice. The dev is right in that from a business sense it's important that things work, whether the code is written like a work of art doesn't matter. However it's also important from a business sense to keep up the quality of the codebase for further development, new developers and when old developers leave.

His claim of "we all solve the problems in a different way" on the other hand is faulty. While programming languages allow you to solve problems in many different ways, you want to stick to standard idioms and patterns. They're proven and they're recognizable by other people who know the standard idioms. You should be wary every time someone comes up with his own "clever solution" for a problem, as it usually means that they're trying to do something in a non-standard way.

I don't comment on the given code because there's not much to comment. Looks a bit odd, but not "dangerous" per se.

Comment: One of the issues is thing you mention ` Of course it can be harmful if younger devs understand it as a valid `; since that microservice development was later on continued by junior developers, one of them notice the problem, but was a bit afraid to talk to him about it, so he talked to me, I checked and I was shocked...

Comment: @Darkves good that you both saw it as problematic. People tend to be defensive about their code even (and sometimes especially) if they're in a senior position, but at least he did offer some explanation instead of just saying "mind your own business". You've taken the issue up with him and he's provided an explanation (and acknowledges that the code isn't great, but it does work). Since this doesn't seem like a serious issue, it's probably not worth refactoring. I imagine the dev will be annoyed if you keep dwelling on this, so make mental notes and go on to find the next codebase oddity :)

Comment: I think I'll ignore the issue, and not search for another mistake :D and just find a better team to work with where things like that are not acceptable where I could fit better (like in my previous company where we had nazi like coding rules) 
Glad to hear your opinion, and thank you for that

Answer (score 1):

I would put validation in the setter methods, rather than just in the construction bits. And I’m guessing there are actual public getters somewhere? At that point I would make actual public properties with private fields.

But those aren’t huge things. If there aren’t public getters in this class, I have more problems with this code. It is forcing inheritance for no clear benefit. Even at that point though, this isn’t a terrible mistake. The code is maybe fragile and maybe a little harder to maintain. And it might be messy when you actually go to serialize them. That isn’t the end of the world. The problems will tend to be isolated to this class and its children, limiting the impact to users and making refactoring not too bad later (depending on serialization dependencies).

Comment: There are public getters, and they are called for serialization. In any case, I can't understand why the properties are not public, so serialization could be done easy... and all other logic is moved to some helper temporary - until he finds a better solution